# More elegant way than using rawQuery for single results?

Tags: android, sqlite

To get multiple results of a query I use `Cursor c = mydatabase.rawQuery("command", null);` and then `while (c.moveToNext()) { ... }`. Works as advertised.

But if I just want to have one result as in `SELECT rowSomething FROM table WHERE [row] = 'Test'` and I know that it will be one result, a string, can I do something like
`String result = mydatabase.StringQuery("Command");`?

Comment: With Room or another SQLite wrapper, yes. But not in the standard Android SQLite API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example with [`DatabaseUtils#stringForQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).